# Why is Objective C runtime needed if appl is compiled as native

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

New to Swift/Objective-c and coming from Java, C# and C++ background. My understanding is that a runtime is needed if the code is non-native as in case of Java or C# an intermediate code is generated which would at Runtime need an environment which translates code to the machine language and we call that a runtime environment (like JRE).

So having read some Q and As on stack overflow it is clear that Swift and Objective-C both are compiled as native binaries. But they need Objective-C runtime to execute them.

I don't know why a runtime is needed if code is already in machine language ?

Is it like a library linked to the program ?

Or Is this objective-C runtime a separate environment which hosts the objective-C/Swift program ? just like JRE ?

Can someone please shed some light on this ?

Thanks,
Ahmed

Comment: In this context, it's like a library linked to the program. An Objective-C/Swift program compiles to machine code that calls a lot of low-level routines like `class_getName` and `objc_msgSend`. The "runtime environment" provides those routines.

Comment: So is this library statically linked to the program or is it picked at runtime from the whatever OS X platform it is running on ?

Comment: It's normally linked dynamically to `/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib`, but it's possible to produce a static binary that will run on a system without that file present.

Answer (score 5):

Many programming languages rely on [runtime libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_library), including C++. These consist of low-level routines to support the programming language's model on that of the hosting operating system. Objective-C's runtime library implements core features such as dynamic method lookup.

Java and C# require a [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine), these are much more involved than runtime libraries.

HTH

Comment: Even a pure C program will have a runtime;  shows up as crt0, IIRC.  Heck, one could argue that *every* program on a multitasking system is relying on a runtime simply because it colludes (collides? :) ) with the kernel's scheduler and I/O management, amongst other things.    No runtime pretty much implies that you are starting from scratch;  no system services at all!